# Confused : what's the best way to use user data in a multiplayer?

Tags: android

I've been investigating how to build a multiplayer game and I'm struggling to understand how to do this. I know Google has good advice on making a client id and linking to the Google play console but I cannot see advice on how to link data from the phone to the (I'm not sure) Google server? I've used shared preferences to save all data so far. Is this a bad idea? Should I be using  sql? How do you transfer. Should I have my own server or can I use Google play?  The idea is my character's stats are compared to the opponent and the better stats win.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would need an API to do this. You don't want to use `SharedPreferences` as these are wiped if the user re-installs the app.

I would recommend using Parse as it's free until you get a big user base and it's pretty easy to use.

https://www.parse.com/

See tutorials here:

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Simple login tutorial to get you started, you could integrate this so each of your users have an account and if they change phone or re-install your app their data will still be there.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/

Grabbing Google account email address to use in your Parse API:

```
public void selectUser() {
    Intent googlePicker = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
    new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, true, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            String selectedEmailAccount = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            emailSelected(selectedEmailAccount); // do something with the users email address in this method

        } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks amazing. Thank you. Can I ask: will I be able to link to Google SignIn and use as a multiplayer?

Comment: It depends what you want to do, you could grab the users Google account with a choose account intent (will edit answer with example), you can then use that email as your Parse API username.

Comment: Would I then call the opponents data and, within their copy of my app on their phone, compare the data and send the results back? Thank you for help.

Comment: It really depends on what type of game it is going to be, it is quite an involved process and you will definitely have to look up some guides or find some samples online, I can't really answer more than what I've given you so far the rest will have to be in your hands. If I were you I'd get Parse working, user accounts working and go from there. If you have to end up going with another API back end then at least you've had some solid experience.

Comment: Thank you for your help: it's given me a solid starting point. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Let me know how you get on or if you get stuck in a specific area. Don't forget to up vote / mark question as answered!